# How to use jquery.html to insert html code inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm on way of building a script like FB search box suggestion. Where, i've an INPUT box where user can enter a name.. and, as soon as user enter a name some suggestion will automatically appear under the INPUT box. All the suggestion, will appear inside an DIV. The code which i'm using is like this...

```
<input name="Emp_Name" id="emplyoee_search">  
<div class="list"></div>
```

The suggestion list which i'm inserting inside that DIV().. i'm getting that by ajax & using jquery.HTML() i'm inserting those list inside of that DIV().

The suggestion list HTML code which i'm inserting in that DIV() is some thing like this..

```
<div class="listItem" align="left">Sunit K Marwah</div>
<div class="listItem" align="left">Sunit Maurya</div>
```

Now, the thing happening is.. i'm successfully able to build the suggestion list inside that DIV(). But, where i'm getting stuck is.. when some one click on any particular suggestion list(names) then, a javascript event need to be fire & the name need to be appear in the given INPUT box.

For java script event firing i'm using JQuery.HTML() & the code is like this..

```
$("div.listItem").click(function () { 
 var string = $(this).text();
 alert(string); 
//console.log(string);
});
```

But, my problem is.. i can successfully shows the list but when i click on the any particular name from suggestion list the java-script event is not firing & i can't able to catch the name.

I'm not a java-script xpert. So, don't know what exactly going wrong at where. Need some help.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an event handler to be in effect for html that you add to the dom dynamically, then the jQuery [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function if what you're looking for.

```
$("div.listItem").live("click", function () {  
   var string = $(this).text(); 
   alert(string); 
   //console.log(string);
});
```

Comment: @mi6 - cool.  I always love when I find a Stack Overflow question that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

look for jquery ui autocomplete plugin it will make life easier for you... also use live with the click event

```
$("div.listItem").live("click",function () { ...}
```

or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$("div.list").delegate(".listItem","click",function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 $(".list div").each(function(){
       alert($(this).text());
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax response should be:

```
<select id='empNameAuto' size='1' onClick='sugAccepted($(this.val));' >
    <option value='value1'>value1</option>
    <option value='value2'>value2</option>
    <option value=n>n</option>
</select>

function sugAccepted(which) {
    $('#Emp_Name').val(which);
}

the drop down list should be css-ed something like:

<div .... style='max-height:..px; overflow:scroll'>the select goes here</div>

That will look like a drop down regular select box.
```

Good luck!

EDIT: actually, I made a mistake here since the idea was to avoid the select altogether. My thinking was correct but the implementation can be done another way:

```
Your (new) ajax response:

<span style='display:block;' onClick="sugAccepted('" + response1 + "'); ">
 response1
</span>
<span style='display:block;' onClick="sugAccepted('" + response2 + "'); ">
 response2
</span>
<span style='display:block;' onClick="sugAccepted('" + response3 + "'); ">
 response3
</span>
<span style='display:block;' onClick="sugAccepted('" + response4 + "'); ">
 response4
</span>

function sugAccepted(which) {
    $('#Emp_Name').val(which);
    get-rid-of-the-suggestion-box
}


the drop down list should be css-ed something like:

<div .... style='max-height:..px; overflow:scroll'>those span go here</div>

[NOW] That will look like a drop down regular select box.
```

EDIT: the location of that "drop down":

How are you positioning the drop down? In case you have not figured it out yet, I would suggest:

```
$('#Emp_Name').keyup( function () {
    ajax-get-suggestion-list;
    if ('#suggestionBox').is(':hidden')) {
        var absH = $('#Emp_Name').offset().top;
        var absL = $('#Emp_Name').offset().left;
        append-box-absolutely-at-absH-and-absL
    }
    drop ajax-response-into-suggestion-box
    $('#suggestionBox').html(ajax-response-of-suggestions);
});
```